# Install Gnome 3.16 in Ubuntu Mate 15.04

Tags: gnome, 15.04, mate

I've just installed Ubuntu Mate and is blazing fast, but I don't like the default desktop, so I have some questions regarding this:

- Can I install Gnome 3.16?
- The speed of Ubuntu Mate is thanks to Gnome 2?
- Ubuntu Mate + Gnome 3.16 is the same as Ubuntu + Gnome 3.16?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use stock Gnome in Ubuntu.  You can install it from the command line:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop

But, I think it may be an older version.

Mate is the development continuation of Gnome 2.

Installing Ubuntu Mate then Gnome will result in the same Gnome being installed as installing stock Ubuntu then Gnome.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question...